# How to pass environment file to service?

Tags: angular

I have 3 different environment files:
environment.dev.ts
environment.prod.ts
environment.stages.ts

To change file which will be used, for example, I pass `--env=prod` into my webpack.config.ts. It works fine.

But I also have a service, where I need to import environment file like this `import { environment } from '../environments/environment.dev';`. When I start webpack in console and type `--env=dev' I need to pass environments.dev.ts into my service; if I type` --env=prod' it should be environments.prod.ts in my service. How can I do this thing? Maybe there is a better way to solve my problem (I need to change URL for different bundles). At this moment URL contains in my environments files.

**UPDATE.**
I found a solution. If you use webpack commands to build app and change environments after `ng eject` add into your webpack.config.js

```
var NODE_ENV;
econst environmentFiles = {
  'dev': 'environments/environment.dev.ts',
  'prod': 'environments/environment.prod.ts',
  'local': 'environments/environment.local.ts'
};
```

into module.exports add

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  NODE_ENV = env;
...
}
```

and

```
"hostReplacementPaths": {
  "environments/environment.ts": environmentFiles[NODE_ENV]
},
```

into AngularCompilerPlugin.

And you can run
`webpack build --env='name_of_your_environment'` and it will change environment.ts file

Answer (score 0):

If you generate your app with the CLI, by default, your development environment will use  `environment.ts`, and `environment.prod.ts` for production environment.

If you want to add more environments, have a look in `.angular-cli.json` :

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
 }
```

You can define more envs if you want

Comment: Hi, merlosy. I know that, but in my case I need to use only webpack file, wich generate after `ng eject`. I have no problem to change my environment.ts files in webpack commands, but I need to change this file in my components and services.
For example this is my environment file
`export const environment = {
  production: false,
  newsfeedDemoUrl: 'newsfeed.demo.dev',
  demoUrl: 'demo.dev',
  onlineUrl: 'online.demo.dev',
  token: 'rtue33o2pp2899s'
};`

Comment: and in my component I import this file like
`import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';`. But I need to change this file, now it's hardoce in my component, but it must change, for diferent urls for prod and dev.
Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Well, in my case i only imported from environment, the build mechanism relying on angular DI replaces the env file with the required one according to the env you specify